# Virtualize Linux running server

Tags: linux, virtualization

I have a home linux server and i don't want lost data from her.
I searching some tool and software to virualization, i want virtualize my running now server and install on it clean hypervisor software. I searching for free tool to do this and now my procesor don't support virtualization and i don't know how it may works on this, if it woorks poor I change procesor with virualzation support.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first - which hypervisor would you be using, VMware has its own tools of doing it, XenServer too has its own way of doing it, im not gonna comment on Virtualbox, chances are aleroot is gonna say its not a hypervisor again ......

Once your have identified that then follow the best practice way of doing a p2v by your selected hypervisor solution.

For some good reading - [Linux P2V ConShell](http://conshell.net/wiki/index.php/Linux_P2V) to have a better understanding and way of doing it safely.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst physical to virtual (p2v) conversions of servers is possible, you generally end up with a virtual server that does not perform well virtually (e.g. requires too many free processors on the host machine, or consumes too much memory).

p2v is really only worth it if you don't have the time to do it properly - e.g. you have end of life hardware with legacy systems on it that have to keep running and you can't rebuild on new hardware.

Since it is a home machine, your data is probably of more value than services running on the server.  So it would most likely be better to get a new Virtual Server and build the services you need, then backup all your data on the old machine, and restore on the new one.

Comment: no running servies have more value in this case;-) if more value was have a data, i just backup this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a way to do this in one, but you could take an image of your current system (example tool http://www.falkotimme.com/howtos/systemimager/) and use that to install a VM.

There was an interesting paper a few years ago about a virus theoretically being able to place the host machine inside a VM and run itself out of the VM, so it was undetectable. It's more theory but I thought it was worth a post: http://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.com/2006/06/introducing-blue-pill.html

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what hypervisor you are using. If it is ESXi, VMWware has a tool to do the conversion: http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/